# Date conversion in Oracle using pl sql?

Tags: oracle11g, plsqldeveloper, data-conversion

I am transferring data from oracle to sql. I wrote a query to get the previous date from oracle Table but what do I need to do if I want data from 15 DEC 2013?

```
SELECT CLOSED,RESOLVED,ACTION FROM 
ADMIN.Data where MODIFIED_DATE >=ADMIN.PKGTIMECONVERSION.TO_TO_GMTU(sysdate-1)
```

I have never done this type of conversion before.

Comment: Please don't tag Oracle questions with SQL Server...

Comment: My bad..next time i wont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the package does or what this really has to do with SQL Server (not 'SQL', which is a language not a product), does this do what you want?

```
SELECT CLOSED,RESOLVED,ACTION FROM 
ADMIN.Data where MODIFIED_DATE >=
  ADMIN.PKGTIMECONVERSION.TO_TO_GMTU(DATE '2013-12-15')
```

Or if you don't like the ANSI notation you can use `TO_DATE('15-DEC-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` instead.